# Override reversed(...) in Python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I need a custom `__reverse__` function for my class that I am deploying on App Engine, so it needs to work with `Python 2.5`. Is there a `__future__` import or a workaround I could use?

Subclassing `list` won't work, as I need my class to be a subclass of `dict`.

**EDIT**:

Using `OrderedDict` will not solve the problems, because the `dict` keys are not the same the same as the `list` items.

This is the object I'm trying to create:

1. My object needs to provide the same attributes as a `list`, i.e. support `iter(obj)` and `reverse(obj)`.
2. The elements must be instances of a special third party class.
3. Each elements is associated with a key.
4. Internally, need to access these objects using their keys. That's why I'd put them in a mapping.

I've revised my implementation to be a `list` subclass instead of a `dict` subclass, so here's what I have now:

```
class Foo(list):

   pat = {}

   def __init__(self):
       for app in APPS:  # these are strings
           obj = SpecialClass(app)
           self.append(obj)
           self.pat[app] = obj

   def __getitem__(self, item):

       # Use object as a list
       if isinstance(item, int):
           return super(Foo, self).__getitem__(item)

       # Use object as a dict
       if item not in self.pat:
           # Never raise a KeyError
           self.pat[item] = SpecialClass(None)
       return self.pat[item]

   def __setitem__(self, item, value):
       if isinstance(item, int):
           return self.pat.__setitem__(item, value)
       return super(Foo).__setitem__(item, value)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Now that my class is a subclass of `list`, my problem is resolved.

Comment: did i miss something; now that your class is a subclass of list why you don't override and use list.reverse() hmmm ?

Comment: @tzzzzz I can use `reversed()` now. Note that `list.reverse()` modifies the list **in place**, which is not what I want. I only wanted to support the built-in `reversed()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__reversed__` isn't supported in 2.5, so your only option if you really need to customize the reversed order of your collection, is to modify the places that you call `reversed` to use something else.

But I'm curious: if you are subclassing `dict`, then the order of items is arbitrary anyway, so what does reversed mean in this case?

Comment: To answer your question: I am keeping two collections in one object: a sequence (actually a `list`) and a mapping (which is the `dict` I'm subclassing, so I'm using it as `self`). A third party library then uses this object (which is essentially a list mock), and it expects a list. So, I have a custom `__iter__` method that iterates over the sequence collection (`pat = []; __iter__ = lambda self: iter(self.pat)`), but I can't handle `reverse(my_object)` with that. That said, perhaps I should subclass `list`, and keep my mapped data in an attribute, and have custom `__{get,set}item__` methods?

Comment: Do the list and dict contain the same keys? Could you use an OrderedDict?

Comment: @Daenyth No, but the dict contains the same **values** as the list items.

Comment: Ok, subclassing `list` instead of `dict` solved the issue, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom `__reversed__` is only possible since 2.6, so you can't simply implement that and have `reversed` working in 2.5. In 2.5 and below, you can however make your custom class still working with `reversed` by implementing the sequence protocol (i.e. implement both `__len__` and `__getitem__`).

A different possibility would be to replace the built-in function `reversed` with a custom function that treats your custom class differently. This could work like this:

```
originalReversed = reversed
def myReversed ( seq ):
    if isinstance( seq, MyCustomClass ):
        # do something special
    else:
        return originalReversed( seq )
reversed = myReversed
```

However, I wouldn't recommend that as it changes the normal behaviour of built-in functions (obviously) and might confuse other users.. So you should rather implement the sequnce protocol to make `reversed` working.